# Is it possible to build a metal wire sphere whose shadow projects the 2d conformal maps of the Riemann Sphere on a flat wall?

Tags: riemann-sphere

Is it possible to build a metal wire hollow sphere whose shadow from a nearby point light source projects the 2d conformal maps of the Riemann Sphere on a flat wall?

I believe that in theory it should be possible, but I was not sure if there would be any physical impracticabilities that would limit such a shadow project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done.  For example, see

https://www.shapeways.com/model/1480313/grid-stereographic-projection.html

The technical name for this way of "casting shadows" is called stereographic projection.  See

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6JgGKViQzbc
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html
- http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2014-02

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this video you provided https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX-0Laeczgk can the cage be flipped 180 degrees and still provide visible shadow of the inverted conformal map?

Comment: Yes.  This is illustrated at minute 2:00 in the following video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0z1fIsUNhO4 -- the entire video is really excellent, by the way.